# EF core, Трансляция запроса

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Использую EF Core для работы с БД. Есть сущность БД, которая имеет ключ на другую таблицу

```
public class ListAdministration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ListPosition Position { get; set; }
}
```

Выполняю select c отложенной загрузкой связанных сущностей, то есть

```
_dbContext.ListAdministrations.AsNoTracking().Select(rec => new ListAdministrationDTO
{
  Id = rec.Id
  PositionName = rec.Position.Name
})
```

в SQL запрос транслируется корректно

```
SELECT c.id as Id, m.Name as PositionName 
 FROM ListAdministrations as c
JOIN ListPositions as m ON m.id = c.positionId
```

Я хочу вынести преобразование в DTO в отдельный метод расширения

```
 public static ListAdministrationDTO ToDto(this ListAdministration administration)
 {
    return new ListAdministrationDTO
    {
      Id = rec.Id
      PositionName = rec.Position.Name
    }    
  }
```

И использовать как

```
_dbContext.ListAdministrations.AsNoTracking().Select(rec => rec.ToDto)
```

В этом случае код метода ToDto не транслируется в SQL, а выполняется после выборки из базы, то есть SQL запрос выглядит так

```
SELECT c.id as Id
 FROM ListAdministrations as c
```

Можно ли без **явного указания include()** и использования **отдельного метода ToDto** приджоинить ListPosition (то есть получить аналогичный результат как в первом варианте)?

Answer (score 5):

Метод `ToDTO` должен возвращать тип `Expression`, чтобы он мог быть транслирован в SQL.

```
public static Expression<Func<ListAdministration, ListAdministrationDTO>> ToDto()
{
    return administration => new ListAdministrationDTO
    {
        Id = administration.Id,
        PositionName = administration.Position.Name
    };
}
```

Обратите внимание, что у метода нет параметров!
Это не метод расширения. Он может быть статическим или экземплярным - это не важно.

Использование:

```
_dbContext.ListAdministrations.AsNoTracking().Select(ToDto());
```

Вызывать нужно именно так: `Select(ToDto())`!
Если написать `Select(x => ToDto())`, то выражение конвертируется в делегат. Таким образом `Expression` исчезнет.

---

Другой способ.
Пишем метод расширения, возвращающий `IQueryable`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<ListAdministrationDTO> ToDto(this IQueryable<ListAdministration> administrations)
    {
        return administrations.Select(administration => new ListAdministrationDTO
        {
            Id = administration.Id,
            PositionName = administration.Position.Name
        });
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
_dbContext.ListAdministrations.AsNoTracking().ToDto();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Так как Вы описали будет работать, но цель вопроса можно ли инкапсулировать и вынести в отдельный метода сам маппинг с Entity to Dto, чтобы его можно было использовать в Expression или IQueryable, чтобы он был раскрыт компилятором и транслирован в SQL

Comment: @ДмитрийСабельников - оба показанных способа транслируются в желаемый SQL. По-другому никак.